# Updating desktop.ini and .ico files

Tags: windows, winapi

We ran into permission error when trying to update desktop.ini and .ico files as a part of running our installer.

We suspect that while our installer attempts to update desktop.ini and .ico files, Windows is triggered to load these files in order to update the folder’s custom icon.
This might cause the error we are experiencing, that either of these files cannot be updated and we receive a permission denied error.

Our question is: What is the formal way of telling Windows that we are trying to update desktop.ini and .ico files and would like Windows not to attempt to load them during this time.

Comment: I'm not aware that there is any API for folder customisation. This is one of the Windows features that the user has control over. I believe that your installer should not be modifying desktop.ini at all.

Comment: "*What is the formal way of telling Windows that we are trying to update desktop.ini and .ico files and would like Windows not to attempt to load them during this time*" - there isn't one. That being said, `desktop.ini` is a *system* file that you should not edit manually. Remove the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY` attributes from the file before editing or deleting it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. 

In order to create a custom icon for a folder Microsoft's documentation instructs to create and edit desktop.ini.

(see:learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini)

This is the case here.

What is the right way to update these files during an installation?

We suspect that when our intaller attempts to update these files it collides with Windows' attempt to update as it detects these files changed.

Thanks,

John.

Comment: @JohnSmith you are *assuming* that is what is happening. Try using [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what is *actually* happening with the file